# Reading JSON file using JavaScript with Wix website builder

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to read the following JSON file (from youtube), I was wondering how I would get the video title using this. I currently have the following code:

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos? 
part=snippet&id=xxxx&key=myapikeygoeshere", 
{method: "get"})
  .then( (httpResponse) => {
if (httpResponse.ok) {
  return httpResponse.json();
} else {
  return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
}
} )
.then(json => console.log(json.title))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Link to json data: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=xxxx

Should also be noted that U am using Wix website builder.

When I look in the console, it simply says undefined.

Update: I found another post where you are able to get the video title and up loader name without using an api key using the following line:
    https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojCkgU5XGdg&format=json

If someone was able to assist me in reading this I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting your api key here

Comment: I have removed it, didn't realise it was there.

Comment: It's still there

Answer (score 0):

Its a cross-domain Ajax call issue (CORS)
You need to enable CORS headers on your domain before fetching youtube api.
If you can't enable CORS headers (since you are on wix)
than you need to simply make a call to your api which will fetch this api from server and return the results.

Below url for making curl call from wix - 
https://support.wix.com/en/article/accessing-3rd-party-services#backend-service-call

Comment: Hi, could you point me in the right direction for making a call to my api which will fetch this from the server and give me the results? 

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: updated the answer with the article for wix specific use case.